# jQuery stop fadein during fadeout

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code [on my site](http://sevensense.co.uk/):

```
$(".name").hover(
    function() { $(".kyle_hover").stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow'); },
    function() { $(".kyle_hover").stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow'); }
);
```

But I have about 4 of these on top of each other, they are hidden and appear when hovered and disappear when left as expected, but the `.stop` method isn't doing what I exepct.

When you hover over the titles quickly, they all stack up on top of each other (as they are built into the HTML) but I want the animation to complete before starting the next one, have I misunderstood stop?

[Quick fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zu6aQ/3/).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you seem to have misunderstood it. `stop()` doesn't clear the queue for all animations, it just stops the animation that's in progress on the exact element it's called on. So, calling `$(".kyle_hover").stop()` will stop this particular element's animation, but if you hover over `$("#gallery")`, its animation will be triggered independently.

In your particular case, I'd just position the fading in/out elements absolutely so that they don't stack up one on above another. The fading in/out will look far more pleasing, and your jQuery code won't require any changes.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't occur to me to position the elements! :D